# How to handle setInverval and clearInterval on react native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to change the value of state [time] every second when a button is pressed. I have the code below, but unfortunately the code doesn't work.
Do you have any suggestion on how can I handle this issue ?

Many thanks !

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const TimeButton = () =>{

  const [time,setTime] = useState(10)
  
  
  let intervalId:any = null;
 
  


  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
         <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={24} color="black" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{time}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={() => {
        intervalId = setInterval(setTime(time+1), 1000)

        }} onPressOut={() => clearInterval(intervalId)}>
          <AntDesign name="caretright" size={59} color="black" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:"center"
  }
})

export default TimeButton;
```

Comment: Don't use a mutable, local `intervalId` to store your intervalId. `useState` for it, so it persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check this demo may hope it will help you https://snack.expo.io/eUOetcDe6

```
    import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import {View,Text,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    let intervalId;
    let Time=10;
    const TimeButton = () =>{
      const [time,setTime] = useState(Time)
      const StartInterval=()=>{
            intervalId=setInterval(() => {
              Time++;
              setTime(Time);
            }, 1000);
      }
      const StopInterval=()=>{
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'black',padding:10}} onPress={StartInterval}>
              <Text style={{color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Start</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{time}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'#6200ee',padding:10}} onPress={StopInterval}>
            <Text style={{color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Stop</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      )
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container:{
        flex:.2,
        flexDirection:'coulam',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:"space-around"
      }
    })

    export default TimeButton;
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much for your help. If you don't mind, could you explain me why "intervalId" if it's in TimeButton the clearinterval function doesn't work?

Comment: Logic is very simple when every your state is updated component will again render so after 1sec  your intervalId variable is changed from setInterval to null

Comment: 2 calls to `StartInterval` will cause you to lose the `intervalId` for the first timer. You might choose to call `StopInterval` from `StartInterval` to ensure that you never lose any timer handles.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to update a state outside the functional component? As in, `setInterval` was set to `intervalId` outside the component, so technically the `setInterval` is calling the function which also include `setTime` from "outside" the component, no?

Answer (score 0):

note that `setInterval` take a callback(fancy name for passing a function to another function), so using `setInterval` should be like

```js
   onPressIn={() => { 

              intervalId = setInterval(() => setTime(time+1), 1000));

   }};
```

and while you are doing some async operation I wont use setTime based on the old state that when being used it may had been changed, so to be more determined use the function version of the setTime to update the state of `time`

```js
  setTime(oldTime => oldTime + 1);
```

Comment: An outer `setInterval` (without a time period) that calls an inner `setInterval` that doesn't use a function for its 1st parameter? This does not make any sense.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake writing solution, I'll fix it